# Redirect only root and html file requests to https, but keep http request as they are

Tags: .htaccess

If user types
`example.com`, `http://example.com` or `http://example.com/x.html` it should always redirect to https

but I'd like to keep hotlinked files accessible through http (some of my old software has hardcoded http paths to web resources and that should still work without redirecting)

How do I modify .htaccess?
I have pieced this that I thought means "if https is off and it is .html page or root, open the page prefixing with https", but it completely breaks the site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: With this you’d be endlessly redirecting the root path, I suppose - because even if the AND between the first two conditions is implicit, it still binds stronger than the OR.